# PHP dynamically create a custom PDF from mySQL database 

Tags: php

I have a requirement to create a custom report based on data stored in a mySQL database. I would like to create a function that will render a PDF on the fly and when finished pop up a save as box or something similar for the user to save, or pop up a new window displaying the PDF giving the option for the user to save.

I have done some research and found a few options but was wondering if someone has done something like this before and has a recommendation. Alot of what I have found is really old or costs money. I would like to find something free if possible.

I want to be able to control exactly where things are placed on the document, insert images, font sizes, etc...

Thanks for any recommendations

Answer (score 2):

I've used [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), and been pretty happy with it.

Comment: i have used fpdf heaps, there are lots of extra code available to do things like rounded rectangles, ploygons etc. i haven't struck any limits yet.